# Selenium WebDriver - Wait for long running queues

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have an application which is used to trigger long running data queues. By long running, I mean around 12-16 hours per queue and either of them cannot be executed in parallel. Each queue has individual steps which need to succeed before the next one runs.

I have already increased the timeouts while initializing ChromeDriver upto 1000 minutes

`webDriver == new ChromeDriver(path,options,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1000));`

I am using `WebDriverWait` for checking after 1000 mins that all steps have been succeeded. In case of a failure, I still have to wait for 1000 minutes before I can tell the dev team about the failure.

Is there a better approach to solve this problem? It is also keeping my browser open for 1000 mins

Comment: Can you break the work up into different scripts? Making stuff up here... script 1 triggers the scenario and script 2 checks to see if it's complete. You run script 1 and then run script 2 every 5 minutes until the process is complete.

Comment: It is definitely possible, but what do we gain with that? Running the queue, is a simple task of clicking a button. Once I have executed it, we don't exactly know when it would finish

Comment: Correct but the problem you are having is that your browser open for almost 17 hours. That's a lot of time for something to go wrong and then you have to start all over. If you break up the work, you run the second script until it succeeds and then stop the test. It doesn't get the test done any sooner (nothing is really going to fix that except DEV optimizing the process) but it will make it more reliable.

Comment: This really isn't a good candidate for automation. You'd be better off getting with DEV and having the application send an automated email when the process is done. Then you don't have to notify anyone, the app does it for you.

Comment: Can you share more of the problem you're trying to solve? Have you tried smaller data sets/queues?

Comment: also, it might be worth using explicit waits, not the implicit wait when configuring the driver. That may give you more control.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question -- is there a better way to solve this problem? With Selenium, not really. You'd have better luck taking a different approach, such as API, than through UI testing. However, it's still possible, just not ideal.

My best idea for this problem would be to set up some sort of controller that can manage your WebDriver instances and also keep track of the 12-16 hour queue time. Since I don't have any specific information about your project architecture or the queues you are testing, this will be a very generic implementation.

Here's a simple DriverManager class, that controls creating & terminating WebDriver sessions:

```
public class DriverManager
{

    public IWebDriver CreateDriver
    {
        // code to initialize your WebDriver instance here
    }

    public void CloseWebDriverSession
    {
        Driver.Close();
        Driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Next, here's a test case implementation that utilizes DriverManager to close & reopen WebDriver as needed.

```
public class TestBothQueues
{
    // this driver instance will keep track of your session throughout the test case
    public IWebDriver driver;

    [Test]
    public void ShouldRunBothQueues
    {
        // declare instance of DriverManager class
        DriverManager manager = new DriverManager();    

        // start a webdriver instance
        driver = manager.CreateDriver();

        // run the first queue
        RunFirstQueue();

        // terminate the WebDriver so we don't have browser open for 12 hours
        manager.CloseWebDriverSession();

        // wait 12 hours
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(12));

        // start another WebDriver session to start the second queue
        driver = manager.CreateDriver();

        // run the second queue
        RunSecondQueue();

        // terminate when we are finished
        manager.CloseWebDriverSession();
    }
}
```

A few notes on this:

You can also convert this code into a while loop if you would like to start a WebDriver instance to check the queue on a time interval. For example, if the queue takes 12-16 hours to finish, you may want to wait 12 hours, then check the queue once per hour until you can verify it is completed. That would look something like this:

```
// first, wait initial 12 hours
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(12));

// keep track of whether or not queue is finished
bool isQueueFinished = false;

while (!isQueueFinished);
{

    // start webdriver instance to check the queue
    IWebDriver driver = manager.CreateDriver();

    // check if queue is finished
    isQueueFinished = CheckIfQueueFinished(driver);

    // if queue is finished, while loop will break
    // if queue is not finished, close the WebDriver instance, and start again

    if (!isQueueFinished)
    {
        // close the WebDriver since we won't need it
        manager.CloseWebDriverSession();

        // wait another hour
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.